# Python interpreter history in anaconda doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, pythoninterpreter

I'm using Python under Anconda in Ubuntu running on WSL2.

When I use arrow keys to go through the command history control characters (I assume) are printed instead of showing the previous commands:

[image]

When not using an Anaconda environment the history works as expected.

I have installed `readline` in the Anaconda environment in attempt to fix it, but that didn't work.

How can I fix this?

Comment: @JustinGardner thanks for your interest and bounty, but I've "solved" this problem with a complete windows reinstallation.

Comment: You can refer to this : https://lornajane.net/posts/2011/navigating-bash-history-with-ctrlr  or additionally you can try editing bashrc .